# Error Recuperar al guardar o recuperar una imagen BD SQLServer

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, asp, imagen

Al guardar la Imagen en la base de datos se guarda en un campo de tipo **Imagen** el problema es que al recuperar la imagen y recibirla en una variable tipo **[ ]byte** haciendo la conversión correcta no puedo visibilizar en el control destinado, he identificado que al enviarla a la base de datos **el numero de bytes es de 139551 byte[139551]**, pero al recuperarla desde la base de datos **el numero de bytes es de 13 byte[13]** obviamente no podría cambiar el tipo del campo a **varbinary(MAX) por soportar solo 8000 bytes**...

**Recuperación de BD**

```
DataTable Tabla = ConsultasMasivasN.ConsultarSoporteIndicadorN(CodigoGI, UsuarioS);
                ViewState["TblSoporte"]=Tabla;
                gridListado.DataSource = Tabla;
                gridListado.DataBind();
                Session["Consulta"] = Tabla;
```

**Handler File**

```
if (context.Session["Consulta"] != null)
            {
                DataTable tbRegistro = (DataTable)context.Session["Consulta"];
                DataRow drRegistro = tbRegistro.Select(string.Format("Codigo={0}", context.Request.QueryString["Codigo"]))[0];
                byte[] imagen = (byte[])drRegistro["Soporte"];
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(imagen, 0, imagen.Length);
            }
```

Agradezco su ayuda!!!!

Comment: Puedes ser más claro en el tipo de datos de la columna en tu base de datos?, cuál es la estructura de la tabla?, qué versión de SQL Server estás usando?

Comment: Tenés que tener mucho criterio al almacenar las imágenes en la base de datos. Podrías almacenar el path y recuperarla desde el disco o si de todas formas queres guardarla en la DB sería bueno que tengas una tabla exclusiva para eso (Id, Imagen). El campo que podrías usar es FILESTREAM https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx

Comment: Gracias, como dice la pregunta el tipo de dato en la base de dato es Imagen(SQLServer 2008 o superior), el punto es que almacena sin problema, pero al recuperarla no se visualiza correctamente... revisare el enlace, no puedo almacenarla local, no es una opción.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, Change the data type in the Database Image field to varbinary(MAX) and use a stored procedure defining SqlDbType.VarBinary to insert the image into the database so I did not lose bytes in the process, before I just saved The variable type [] byte in the Image field.

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SoporteIndicador](
    [Codigo] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CodigoIM] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CodigoGI] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Soporte] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [NombreSoporte] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [UsuarioRegistro] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FechRegistro] [datetime] NOT NULL
```

**Error:**

```
public static int RegistrarSoporteIndicador(SoporteIndicador soporteIndicador)
        {
            int Ingreso = 0;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = Conexion.ObtenerConexion())
            {
                SqlCommand Ingresar = new SqlCommand(string.Format(
                    "Insert Into SoporteIndicador (CodigoIM,CodigoGI,Soporte,NombreSoporte,UsuarioRegistro,FechRegistro) values ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}')",
                soporteIndicador.CodigoIM,
                soporteIndicador.CodigoGI,
                soporteIndicador.Soporte, //Type []byte                soporteIndicador.NombreSoporte,
                soporteIndicador.UsuarioRegistro,
                soporteIndicador.FechRegistro), conexion);
                Ingreso = Ingresar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conexion.Close();
            }
            SqlConnection cerrarcon = Conexion.CerrarConexion();
            return Ingreso;
        }
```

**Solución:**

```
public static int RegistrarSoporteIndicador(SoporteIndicador soporteIndicador)
        {
            int Ingreso = 0;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = Conexion.ObtenerConexion())
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("PA_Guardar_Registro", conexion))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CodigoIM", soporteIndicador.CodigoIM);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CodigoGI", soporteIndicador.CodigoGI);
                    SqlParameter imageParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Soporte", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary);
                    imageParam.Value = soporteIndicador.Soporte;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("NombreSoporte", soporteIndicador.NombreSoporte);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UsuarioRegistro", soporteIndicador.UsuarioRegistro);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FechRegistro", soporteIndicador.FechRegistro);


                    Ingreso = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conexion.Close();
                }
            }
            SqlConnection cerrarcon = Conexion.CerrarConexion();
            return Ingreso;
        }
```